# JQuery Validation between 2 textfield

Tags: jquery

I have two textfields with numbers only. In the first Textfield i have the number 100.
When i write in the second Textfield a number greater than 100 i want to get an alert, where i can write only a number smaller than 100.

```
Limit : <input type="text" class="inputGU" id="Sel1" readonly="readonly" value="100" >
<br><br>
Get :<input type="text" class="inputGU" id="Sel2" value="" >​
```

The value of the second textbox must be smaller than the value of the first textbox

Is this possible with JQuery??

http://jsfiddle.net/ExaVH/

Comment: Try the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) first and then come back if you have any questions.

Comment: return (eval($("#Sel2").val()) <= eval($("#Sel1").val()));

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I hope that is a joke, `eval()` on input nothing but problems.

Comment: @Mark you are right...my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

js:

```
$('#Sel2').change(function(){
    var inputGUVal = Number ($('#Sel2').val());
    var inputGULimit = Number ($('#Sel1').val());
    if (inputGUVal > inputGULimit){
        alert ('Choose a number below a ' + inputGULimit )
    }
})​
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/ExaVH/15/

Comment: It works great THX. Just one question, how can i bind this with the formular and the submit button, where are these two Textfields, that when i write a value bigger than the vlue from the first field, that i can't submit? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but paste your current code in another Question with jsFiddle.

Comment: OK it's done:
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060699/if-alert-do-not-submit-form

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible with jQuery, you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#Sel2').change(function(e){
        var val1 = $('#Sel1').val();
        if(parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt(val1)){
            alert("The value must be smaller than "+val1);
            $(this).val('');        
        }   
    });        
});​
```

See it in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhLKg/1/)

Comment: There's nothing but the OP's HTML in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt28U/).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("input").change(function() {

        if(parseInt($("#Sel2").val()) > parseInt($("#Sel1").val()))
        {
            alert("exceeded limit");
        }
    }
);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ExaVH/7/