# If Alert do not Submit Form

Tags: jquery

I have two textfields and a jquery code who who gives me an alert, when the value of the second textfield is greater then the value of the first Textfield. I found the code and it works great, but I need to transfer these control to an hyperlink, who submit to continue if the value of the second textfield is smaller. If it is not, than I want to get the alert and the formular can't submit to continues

```
$('#Sel2').change(function(){
    var inputGUVal = Number ($('#Sel2').val());
    var inputGULimit = Number ($('#Sel1').val());
    if (inputGUVal > inputGULimit){
        alert ('Choose a number below a ' + inputGULimit )
    }
})​
```

See the Code in [action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExaVH/20/)

Answer (score 3):

Prevent submission based on the condition:

```
$("a").on('click', function (e) {
   if ($("#Sel2").val() > $("#Sel1").val()) {
      e.preventDefault();   
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExaVH/21/

Comment: There is an example on the jQuery page for submit() which is the event when the submit button is clicked. (That's another choice than the "click" event.) [(Click for info)](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: You could also just `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

You could show or hide the submit button based on the validation...

```
$('#Sel2').change(function(){
    var inputGUVal = Number ($('#Sel2').val());
    var inputGULimit = Number ($('#Sel1').val());
    if (inputGUVal > inputGULimit){
        alert ('Choose a number below a ' + inputGULimit );
        $("#button").hide();
    } else {
        $("#button").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event's `preventDefault` method. For more refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Answer (score 0):

Just add some onClick event that triggers the validating function have there, and if it passes continue to the submission. Like this:

```
$('#myLinkId').click(function(){
var inputGUVal = Number ($('#Sel2').val());
    var inputGULimit = Number ($('#Sel1').val());
    if (inputGUVal > inputGULimit){
        alert ('Choose a number below a ' + inputGULimit )
    } else {
    //Your Submission Code here.
})​
```

Like I said, I'd replace the click function with an onClick event though.